# Horizontal Form: Text Input next to label not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the label in the same line as the text box in a Bootstrap 4 horizontal form. Doesn't seem to work. The text boxes always show up in the next line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
  <label for="first_name" class="col-form-label">First Name</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name">
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gunnersfan/mrc4tdu1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `col-*` must be in `.row`. Use the grid column class on the labels and input wrappers...

http://www.codeply.com/go/TUs7hGHnXP

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="Street" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Street</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Street" name="Street">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="City" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">City</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" name="City">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/TUs7hGHnXP

Comment: This way you have nested grids in the layout, which will make more complex forms impossible.

Answer (score 0):

For flex layout you also can use inline form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="email" class="mr-sm-2">Email address:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="email">
  <label for="pwd" class="mr-sm-2">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="pwd">
  <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2">
    <label class="form-check-label">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

See [Inline forms](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms), [Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) and [Flexbox](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the previous bootstrap horizontal form like the following

```
<form>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</div></form>
```